# reading Excel file with xlwings gives me "ValueError: microsecond must be in 0..999999"

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have an Excel-file from which I want to use 2 columns for a pandas data frame. The first column is supposed to be the index and has dates with times (day month year hours minutes). The second column has the corresponding values. When I use the following code:

```
df= acc_used_range.options(
    pd.DataFrame,
    index= 1, 
    header= 1, 
    chunksize= 10000
).value
```

I get the following error message:

`ValueError: microsecond must be in 0..999999`

It must have something to do with the dates. They look like this in Excel (no microseconds, just minutes):

```
01.01.2021 00:00
01.01.2021 00:15
01.01.2021 00:30
...
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a pywin32 issue: see [this issue](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1466) and [this issue](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1655).

Comment: Thank you so much! It was a bug in pywin32. After an update of that package it works.

Answer (score 1):

As BigBen suggested, this is a bug in pywin32 that has been fixed. If you get this error, update your pywin32 package. That should solve it.